# RXJava get object which caused exception in on error handler

Tags: java, rx-java

is there any convenient way to get object which caused any exception in onError handler?

I want to do something like:

```
 observable.subscribe(
            unit -> {
               //something can throw ex here..
            },
            error->logger.error("error on {}", unit, error));
```

Answer (score 3):

Some errors will connect to a value, such as errors from `map` or `filter`. RxJava will call `onError(rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable)` for such errors. You can get the value from `OnErrorThrowable.getValue`.

However, some errors won't connect to a value. RxJava will just send the error directly to `onError`.